# Get a list of location 100 meters far from a geo point

Tags: android, geocoding, android-location

I have a list of places in my database, they all have a latitude / longitude.

In my app, I got the user location and I want to fetch all places which are 100 meters away from him.

To do it, I add 100 meters to his latitude, and longitude

I tried to do something like this:

```
    double radius = 100; // 100 meters

    double limitLatitudeNorth = latitude + radius;
    double limitLatitudeSouth = latitude - radius;

    double limitLongitudeWest = longitude - radius;
    double limitLongitudeEast = longitude + radius;

    StringBuffer query = "latitude < '" + limitLatitudeNorth + "' AND latitude > '" + limitLatitudeSouth + "' AND longitude < '" + limitLongitudeWest + "' AND longitude > '" + limitLongitudeEast + "'";
```

But of course, laitude and longitude are not meters, so I don't know how make the sum.

What is the formula? I heard that it depends of the position in the globe. Let's say I'm in France.

A lot of apps do that (ie: LINE) I thought I will easily find a code for that, but I didn't: (

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [distanceTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29) method inside Location class. Do the following:

```
Location location = new Location();
location.setLatitude(latitude);
location.setLongitude(longitude);

Location locationFromDB = new Location();
locationFromDB.setLatitude(latitudeFromDB);
locationFromDB.setLongitude(longitudeFromDB);

float dist = location.distanceTo(locationFromDB);
if(dist<100f){
     //do here your magic
}
```

Comment: the question is find all places with in 100 meter .You are find the distance between two location.

Comment: @RishabhBhardwaj Read the question and the answer again.{

Answer (score 0):

For distances in latitude (which trace a great circle through the poles) then 1 minute of arc = 1 nautical mile = 1852 metres (approx). Thus 1 degree = 111.12 km

For changes in longitude you need to multiply this factor by the cosine of the latitude. So at the equator the distance change is the same as for changes in latitude, at the poles (cos 90 degrees = 0) the lines of equal longitude all converge to a point.